# Filling An Array With random Integer Values

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I bought a JavaScript book and am working my way through. I've reached a part of the book that doesn't make sense. I'm hoping you guys and girls will be able to clarify as the book doesn't.

Please see the code below that generates 6 random numbers and renders them to a div with `id=panel`.

```
function init(){
var panel = document.getElementById('panel');
var i, rand, temp, str, num = [];

for (i = 1; i < 50; i ++){
    num[i] = i;
}

for (i = 1; i < 50; i ++){
    rand = Math.ceil(Math.random()*49);
    temp = num[i];
    num[i] = num[rand];
    num[rand] = temp;
}

str = 'Your six lucky numbers:<br>';
for (i = 1; i < 7; i ++){
    str += num[i];
    if (i !==6){str += ' - ';}
}
panel.innerHTML += str;

}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```

The book says that the second loop (that initilizes the random variable) contains a sort algorithm that ensures no two elements contain the same number.

I'm not sure how this is possible, I don't see any code in there that stops `rand` containing a duplicate number and consequently having that value stored in `num`. The book doesn't really provide much of an explanation of what is going on.

Could someone please let me know how, if at all, loop two is preventing 'num` from containing the same number?

Thanks all

P.S. Sorry if this question doesn't adhere to Stack Overflow guidelines. I don't come on here often, only when I get really stuck and can't find an answer elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first for loop is just creating an array of 49 elements, with each array element being equal to its index:

```
num[1] = 1
num[2] = 2
etc.
```

The second for loop, which is the focus of your question, randomly shuffles this ordered array.

As an Example:

1st iteration of the for loop, rand gets the value of say *23*, the logic in the loop then swops the value in num[23] with the value in num[1] so that you end up with:

```
num[1] being equal to 23 (because num[23] was equal to 23 as per above)
num[23] being equal to 1
```

2nd iteration of the for loop, rand gets the value of say *18*, the logic in the loop then swops the value in num[18] with the value in num[2] so that you end up with:

```
num[2] being equal to 18 (because num[18] was equal to 18 as per above)
num[18] being equal to 2
```

This will happen 49 times.

This is also the reason for Math.random() being multiplied with 49, there is only 49 array elements with values.

TL;DR; Ordered array gets shuffled.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I had to go through it the exact same way you just did to understand, but wasn't sure I was right.

What is there to stop `Math.random()` from generating the same number twice?

Comment: There isn't, but lets say random generates 32 on both the 3rd and the 15th iteration. It will swop the 32th and 3rd value, so num[32] = 3 and num[3] = 32 after the swop. Now, on the 15th iteration, it will swop num[15] with num[32], but now num[32] contains 3, so num[15] = 3 and num[32] = 15 after the swop. So it does not really matter if it generates a random value more than once.

Comment: thank you so much! I couldn't for the life of me figure that one out. I understood what the program was doing, just not the effect it would cause. Thank you again for the breakdown, just what I needed +1 :D

Answer (score 2):

You can think of the two loops as follows: the first one generates a deck of 49 "cards" (represented here by the numbers 1 through 49). The second loop then shuffles those "cards", by repeatedly swapping each card with a random one.

Note **there are two issues** with the code. First, it is unnecessary to shuffle the entire array when only 6 elements will be selected. So the second loop could end at 6 instead of 50.

But there is a more serious issue with the code, it uses the **wrong algorithm to shuffle array elements**. This algorithm does not produce all possible permutations of the elements with the same probability.

Here's the correct version:

```
for (i = 1; i < 50; i ++){
    rand = i + Math.floor(Math.random()*(50 - i));
    temp = num[i];
    num[i] = num[rand];
    num[rand] = temp;
}
```

The idea is to swap the current element in the loop, only with a subsequent element (including itself). Note that if you write the above loop to run backwards (i.e. from 49 to 1) it makes it slightly more simple and I prefer that approach.

Comment: I wouldn’t say the second issue is all that serious — at least not in this scenario. It’s “lucky numbers”, not rocket science.

Comment: Well, the correct algorithm is not significantly more complicated and there is no reason to teach people to use the wrong algorithm.

Comment: for i equal to 1, that would return possibly 50 as an index, which does not exist (if Math.random() returns 0.9999 then 0.9999*(51-1) + 1 is equal to 49.99 of which the ceiling is 50 ) but agree, it is better to learn some of these rules about random early on

Comment: @HeinrichHenning I think I fixed it now.

Comment: @redneb his array contains values and indexes from 1 to 49, not 50 :-) should be `rand = i + Math.floor(Math.random()*(50- i));`

Comment: Thanks for the help @redneb.

Wouldn't `Math.floor()` round down and generate a number from 0.0-49?

Also to see my understanding is correct. Each iteration, the number that `Math.random` is being multiplied by is one less each time `i` increments in the loop?

Thanks again :D

Comment: @Pete Yes, on each iteration, we want `rand` to be a random number in the range from `i` to 49. So we mush allow 0 as a possibility (hence the use of `floor`) and we must decrease the number to multiply `Math.random` with.

Answer (score 1):

This loop creates a sorted array from 1 to 49:

```
for (i = 1; i < 50; i ++){
    num[i] = i;
}
```

---

This loop *reorders* each position (`i`) of the array with another *random position* `rand` by swapping the two. It’s not generating new random numbers, just randomly reordering existing numbers. `rand` is an *index*, not a value in this case. No two numbers can be the same because the first loop only placed one instance of each number in the array.

```
for (i = 1; i < 50; i ++){
    rand = Math.ceil(Math.random()*49);
    temp = num[i];
    num[i] = num[rand];
    num[rand] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. My understanding was correct from what everyone has told me. 

What I'm still puzzled about is `Math.ceil(Math.random()*49);` generates a random number between 1 and 49. Although it only loops through 49 times. Is it not possible for `Math.random` to generate - for example - 14 twice?

Comment: It is almost certain that it wil generate the same number twice. So one number will be swaped with 14 then this number will be swapped again with another. It is even possible that the number comes back to its original place. But hey, that's randomness !
Even if I used it I have the filling that this algorithm is biased. I think it's better to fill another array picking random numbers in the first one.

Answer (score 1):

This loops fills and array with 50 integers from 1 to 50.

Then it just mixes them. The rand variable is used to point a random index in the array.